# Undefined reference when dynamically linking with gcc in cygwin

Tags: c, gcc, linker, cygwin, dynamic-linking

(This is `gcc 3.3.1` (long story -- blame NIST) on Cygwin.)

I have compiled some source files with `gcc -c -fPIC ...` to get .o files.

Then I did:

```
$ gcc -shared -o foo.dll foo.o bar.o
```

But when I go to use it:

```
$ gcc -o usefoo.exe usefoo.o -L. -lfoo
  usefoo.o:usefoo.cpp:(.text+0x2e0): undefined reference to `_get_template_size'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, if **using the same .o files** I instead do:

```
$ ar rcs libfoo-static.a foo.o bar.o
```

The link against that is successful:

```
$ gcc -o foo.exe foo.o -L. -lfoo-static
```

What is weird to me is that as you can see below, the reference in question is present in both the .a and the .dll.  So why the error when linking against the .dll?

Reference is found in the shared library:

```
$ nm foo.dll|grep get_template
1001b262 T _get_template_size
```

And it's also in the static library:

```
$ nm libfoo-static.a |grep get_template
00000352 T _get_template_size
```

And here's the reference to the symbol generated in the file that wants to use the function:

```
$ nm usefoo.o
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 t .text
0000012c T __Z12ErrorMessagei
         U ___main
         U __alloca
         U _atoi
         U _get_template_size
0000026c T _main
         U _printf
```

---

**Updated to address Marco's answer**

Interestingly/annoyingly, when I try to make a minimum test example of this I can't make it happen (though it happens every time with the real thing):

*func1.h*:

```
#ifndef FUNC1_H
#define FUNC1_H

int func1(int i);

#endif
```

*func1.c*:

```
#include "func1.h"

int func1(int i) {
  return 2*i;
}
```

*usefunc.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func1.h"

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", func1(10));
}
```

Then:

```
$ rm *.o *.dll *.a

$ gcc -fPIC -I. -c func1.c usefunc.c

$ gcc -shared -o func.dll func1.o

$ gcc -L. -o usefunc.exe usefunc.o -lfunc

$ ./usefunc.exe
20
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer (in that it solves my link problem) on a Cygwin web page:  http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html

What I ended up having to do was create the shared library and do the final link like this:

```
$ gcc -shared -o cygfoo.dll \
      -Wl,--out-implib=libfoo.dll.a \
      -Wl,--export-all-symbols \
      -Wl,--enable-auto-import \
      -Wl,--whole-archive *.o \
      -Wl,--no-whole-archive

$ gcc -L. -o usefoo.exe usefoo.o -lfoo
```

But I'd still love to know why I didn't have to do this for my simple test.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure, but afaik Windows has namespaces per module (like exe or .dll). When statically linking you are putting everything in one .exe, thus one module, one namespace.

When dynamically linking, you create an two modules (1 exe, 1 dll), and they both have their namespaces.

You need to export the symbol from the DLL for this to work iirc (read up on importlibs, e.g. in the excellent [Linkers and Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

Comment: Interesting!  Two things to note: (1) With the actual code in question, if I add calls to other things in the shared library, they also show up as undefined under a dynamic link -- so it's not just that specific function.  This supports your answer.  However... (2) When I try to make a simple test of this, the simple test works fine under a dynamic link!  (See the update to my question).

Comment: No idea. There might be helper functionality in the compiler here and there, I don't know the various windows ports that well. Btw PIC on Windows ?!?